# Как автоматически отправлять сообщения в Discord через Python и Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, discord, xpath

Пишу небольшую программу для автоматической отправки постов через Selenium, использую метод:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/main/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]").send_keys("HELLO")
```

Пишет что нужен не div, а input, однако в исходном коде тег input отсутствует для поля ввода, в интернете нашел такой метод:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/main/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div')
```

Но он не работает, значение Xpath беру отсюда:

[image: ScreenDiscord]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему самостоятельно, если кому надо: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/main/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]')`

Заменил драйвер Firefox на Chrome